# Nested for loop issue - help needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm a beginner with .Net and I need little help with the for loop. I want to print all messages from two users, and format the messages in (li). However, when rightFilter doesn't have more messages, the (li) is making copies, as it's on the image.

How can I fix this?

```
     @foreach (var left in leftFilter)
        {
            @foreach (var right in rightFilter)
            {

                <li>@left.Message</li>
                <li style="text-align:right;">@right.Message</li>
            }
         }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN7vB.png)

Comment: How are `leftFilter` and `rightFilter` related? Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? Also don't use `if (rightFilter.Count() != 0)` but use `if (rightFilter.Any())`

Comment: leftFilter is taking his messages, rgihtFilter is taking from the other user

Comment: What you probably want is roughly `@foreach(left) { <li>@left</li> } @foreach(right) {<li>@right</li>}`.  That is to say put all the lefts in the list, and then put the rights.  Right now, with nested loops, you are doing the cross product of the two lists.  Because it's a product, if one of the lists is empty, you won't get anything.  If you have 2 items in `left` and 4 items in `right`, I'm assuming you want 6 items total (`2 + 4`), not 8 (`2 x 8`)

Comment: @Robert - Please show us a [mcve]. Please provide input data as valid c# code, and your expected output. Please then provide us with code that actually runs and demonstrates the issue you're facing. Right now there is not enough information in your question to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: @RobIII indeed, though if it's a collection that knows it's count without a list traversal, using `.Count > 0` Is ok (Length if it's an array)

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit your question to include an answer. Post an answer

---

You didn't do a great job of explaining the problem- "hi guys this code doesn't produce the output I want ..." doesn't help us know what you *do* want

It looks like you want to take two lists and interleave their items so you print the value from list1 then list2, over and over

If the items are related positionally I think I might have used a table rather than a html list, and there isn't any need to get heavy with linq for this; remember simple loops:

```
@for(int x = 0; x < left.Length; x++){
  <li>@left[x].Message</li>
  <li style="text-align:right;">@right[x].Message</li>
}
```

Or if you want them to align, two TD inside a TR per loop

Your original code's essential problem was that for every item in left (let's say 10 items) it would print out the entire right list, so you end up with the right list repeated 10 times (110 lines output). You can't easily use a loop inside a loop to achieve what you want, but if you'd like to see a ridiculous example:

```
int x = 0;
foreach(var l in left){
  int y = 0;
  <li ...>
  foreach(var r in right){
    if(x == y++)
      <li ...>
  }
  x++;
}
```

The `if` ensures the inner loop only outputs 10% of the time..